# How do I specify dependencies in a .NET Standard Class Library?

Tags: .net-core, nuget-package, .net-standard

A .NET Standard Class Library doesn't use a `.nuspec` file; there is a "Package" tab in the project settings where you enter all the metadata for the NuGet package. These go in the `.csproj` file.

I want to create a solution with projects A and B, where project B depends on project A. Both need to go on NuGet as separate packages. But if someone installs the NuGet package for B, it should also install the package for A.

How do you specify this simple dependency for a .NET Standard Class Library? I'm not assuming that adding a reference will be enough to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I have found it is not yet supported in [.csproj](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/msbuild-targets) files and you should use [.nuspec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/schema/nuspec) to specify dependencies. Have a look how they do it in [xUnit](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/tree/master/src), for example.

Answer (score 7):

NET Standard .csproj files use `PackageReference` and `ProjectReference` MSBuild items to control dependencies on packages loaded from NuGet or your solution, respectively. They both support metadata tags `PrivateAssets`, `IncludeAssets`, `ExcludeAssets`, which control what exactly and how your project depends on in those dependencies. By default, all dependencies are auto-generated by the Visual Studio with `PrivateAssets`, which means those dependencies are consumed, but they're not marked as dependencies for consumers of your project (which is gonna be a package in NuGet).
So, you just need to replace the `PrivateAssets` metadata with the `IncludeAssets` (maybe with proper values).
For example, my SuperPackage.csproj file looks like below:

```
..................
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers" Version="2.6.0">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="11.0.2">
      <IncludeAssets>compile</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ClassLibrary1\ClassLibrary1.csproj">
      <IncludeAssets>compile</IncludeAssets>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

So, I have the `PackageReference` to the 'Newtonsoft.Json' package from NuGet marked as a dependency, and the `ProjectReference` to the ClassLibrary1 project within the single solution.
When the SuperPackage project is built with checked 'Generate NuGet package on build', I get the following SuperPackage.nupkg:

[image]

Check this doc for more details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files

Comment: This solved my problem, but the important part is to check **Generate NuGet package on build** in the "Package" project properties tab. I initially used `nuget pack` from the command line and the .nuspec file was missing the `<Dependencies>` element. After changing the project settings to generate the package on build, this element appears in the .nuspec file.

Comment: If creating a package using an Azure Pipeline, I found that you need to use the `dotnet` tasks rather than the `nuget` tasks for these dependencies to make it into the nupkg result.